# Why losing query paramenters on action URI of GET FORMS are designed that way?

Tags: get, forms

When submitting this form:

```
<form action="/Url?id=5" method="get">
    <input name="somedata" value="10"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I wasn't able to find the spec and I'm not sure if the behavior I'm getting is correct or something is going wrong.

When submitting that form, the result query string is :

```
 /Url?somedata=10
```

hence the id=5 is lost, even if it's part of the action URI. Someone could explain why is it designed that way or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a hidden field with the id:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="5" />
```

This should give the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do know that one can use hidden fields to get the values on query. The question is more about *why* the query parameters on the URI action aren't passed in.

Comment: Think of the query part of your action attribute as "the default". My guess is that the browser would have a difficult job combining two sets of query prameters and therefore choose to throw away the "default" one.